# How should I change the path name of time series to avoid reporting error in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: path, apache-iotdb, iotdb

> IoTDB> create timeseries root.xt.dcsfw.other.21D.21DPU36COMA130
>
> Msg: 700: Error occurred while parsing SQL to physical plan: line 1:58 mismatched input '' expecting {ID, QUOTED_ID}

Is there any problem with the grammar of this time series in Apache IoTDB: root.xt.dcsfw.other.21D.21DPU36COMA130? When I tried to create this time series, the backstage error prompted that the path is illegal. I also tried the same format with "21D" changed to "21E" and "21F", and IoTDB has no problem using these as the path name. Can anyone suggest how should I correct this time series name if I still want to use "21D"?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add backquotes, and write the command like `` root.xt.dcsfw.other.`21D`.21DPU36COMA130 ``. Since if you do not add backquotes, 21D will be recognized as 21d, which becomes the meaning of 21 days in Apache IoTDB. Also, the datatype needs to be specified, `with datatype=int32`.